# How can I fix this Linq Query that uses both 'and' 'or' values

Tags: c#, linq

I have created this query and want to filter by a text value and date range which contains and OR statement.  I can't seem to get the parenthesis correct.  I have this but it is ignoring the date range.

```
 DateTime Date1 = dpReceived1.SelectedDate.Value;
 DateTime Date2 = dpReceived2.SelectedDate.Value;
 var strComment = cBoxComments.Text;
 var results = data.tblInmates.Where(a => a.comments.Contains(cBoxComments.Text) && 
    (((a.RecDate >= Date1 || a.RecDate <= Date2)))).Take(RadGridMax);
 RadGrid1.DataSource = results.ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.RecDate);
 RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't know the specifics  of your data, but I think your `||` is including too much.  Change it to `&&` and see if that helps.

Comment: We need more information to help you, such as what your inputs and sample data are.  One example issue would be that if the dates have times, the end date should add 1 day and subtract 1 second or millisecond, e.g., if you want everything that happened from 2/12/2018 to 2/12/2018, the end date would need to encompass all the seconds of the current day (2/12/2018 11:59:59 PM).

Comment: You've definitely got unnecessary parentheses in there.  The way to solve your problem is by *understanding the problem, understanding the language, and carefully designing a solution*, not by *randomly changing parentheses until it works*.

Comment: @EricLippert: Most defenitely. To extend on that, I'm not even sure that it has to be `||`. It also could be `&&`, depending on the scenario.

Comment: What I would do here is decide what *concept* you are trying to represent and then write a helper.  For example, if you mean to represent "the date of the sale is not in a blackout period for this stock" then write a helper extension method `InBlackoutPeriod` that returns a bool and write `... && !a.RecDate.InBlackoutPeriod(BlackoutStart, BlackoutEnd)`. Now you have a method which you can independently test for correctness.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @EricLippert comments did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for your comments using the suggestion provided I fix the query so it now works.  This is what is working for me.

```
DateTime Date1 = dpReceived1.SelectedDate.Value;
DateTime Date2 = dpReceived2.SelectedDate.Value;
var strComment = cBoxComments.Text;
var results = data.tblInmates
    .Where (a => a.comments.Contains(cBoxComments.Text) && 
               a.RecDate >= Date1 && a.RecDate <= Date2)
    .Take(RadGridMax);
RadGrid1.DataSource = results.ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.RecDate);
RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

My problem was in a misconfigured nested IF statement.